# php global variable and instance variable utilization

Tags: php

I'm having hard time accomplishing one simple task. I have a method that would generate random number and depending on the outcome assign specific outcome to an array variable. What i want to do is get that array variable through instance method which would be called from the other class.

```
   <?php

   class MyClass
   {
         public $results = array(array());

         public function simulated_games()
         {
             $game_series1=array(23,34,56);
             $game_series2=array(31,42,67);

             $iter_wins=array(array());

             for($i=0; $i<10;$i++)
             {
                 $random = rand(0,100);
                 for($b=0; $b<1;$b++)
                 {

                   if($random <= $game_series1[0])
                   {
                        $iter_wins[$i][$b]=3;
                   }

                   else if($random <= $game_series2[0]+$game_series2[1])
                   {
                        $iter_wins[$i][$b]=1;
                   }
                 }
             }

            $results=$iter_wins;
        }

        >here i create method just to return variable
        public function get_simulated_games()
        {
          return $this->results;
        }
   }



  <?php

  $a= new MyClass();
  $a->simulated_games();

  $array = array();
  >here is the issue, it return just 1, but supposed to return range numbers
  $array=$a->get_simulated_games();

  for($f=0; $f<sizeof($array);$f++)
  {
    for($g=0; $g<5;$g++)
    {
        echo $array[$f][$g];
    }
        echo '<br>';
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: `simulated_games()` is modifying local variable, but not instance one

Comment: And `$random`, `$game_series1` and `$game_series2` aren't defined in the `simulated_games` method.

Comment: `simulated_games()` does not seem to be doing anything at all except generate undefined variable warnings.

Comment: thank you guys for the comments. i've modified code slightly, declaring local variable inside the simulated_games() method, and reassigning it to an instance variable $results. stil wouldnt work

Comment: What is the purpose of `$iter_wins[$i][$b];`? You are not assigning anything to that variable so it just generates `Undefined offset` warnings.

Comment: i actually do, just forgot to put it here, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the error in results.

You modify interal function variable which is not set instead of class variable

change

```
$results=$iter_wins;
```

to

```
$this->results=$iter_wins;
```